# c# distinct doesn't work. what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm developing an asp.net core application.
I have a code for getting property values.

```
var properties = _context.Properties.Select(p => new {
    p.Name,
    Values = p.Values.Distinct()
}).Distinct();
```

But Distinct() doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work"? Which `Distinct` do you mean?

Comment: I'm getting the same elements. And I mean the second Distinct.

Comment: _What_ elements are you getting? Show some inputs, your expected outputs, and actual output, and point out what's wrong.

Comment: I'm getting a properties with included values. And some properties repeating.

Comment: I am asking you to show the actual _values_ of those properties that you are putting in and getting out, not just describe what they are _like_, because this is the clearest way for you to explain what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Try this instead `context.Properties.SelectMany(p => p.Values.Select(v => new { p.Name, Value = v})).Distinct().GroupBy(x => x.Name, x => x.Value).Select(grp => new { Name = grp.Key, Values = grp });`  that should give you all the unique Name-Value pairs and then group them on name with a collection of Values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the second `Distinct` does not know how to compare the items. Probably you mean distinct by name, instead it does distinct by all the properties.

Instead of creating an anonymous type, create a named one (i.e. `Property`). Then declare a `IEqualityComparer<T>` for this type:

```
class PropertyNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<Property>
{
    public bool Equals(Property x, Property y) => x.Name.Equals(y.Name);
    public int GetHashCode(Property p) => p.Name.GetHashCode();
}
```

(for sake of simplicity, I'm not handling nulls here.)

```
var properties = _context.Properties.Select(p => new Property {
    Name = p.Name,
    Values = p.Values.Distinct()
})
.AsEnumerable()
.Distinct(new PropertyNameComparer());
```

Note the `.AsEnumerable()` to separate the query from the second `Distinct` to make it LINQ-to-Objects, because EF cannot convert the `IEqualityComparer<T>` to SQL.

But the real question is, why are you getting duplicate properties in the first place? And if you do, what do you want to happen to the values of the duplicates? Will they contain the same values or different values? My implementation just takes the first property with its values and ignores the values of the duplicates. Instead, you might want to group by name and to union the values. But that's not clear from your question.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I'm getting an error: **'IEnumerable << anonymous type: Name, IQueryable << anonymous type: >> Values >> "does not contain a definition for" Distinct ", and the most appropriate overloaded extension method is" Queryable.Distinct <Property> (IQueryable <Property> , IEqualityComparer <Property>) "requires a recipient of the type" IQueryable <Property> "**

Comment: Because you are still using `new { ... }`, which results in an anonymous type. Use `new Property { ... }` instead to get a known type. You can also use another type, as long as it matches `T` in `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: C# compares anonymous objects by property, not by reference, however the `Values` property is going to be compared by reference because of its type. If the `Values` property were left out, the `Distinct` would produce only one result per value of `Name` since `string`s compare by value, even though they would still be different instances.